# Submitting tasks to a thread-pool gives RejectedExecutionException

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk

I am working on a social game running mostly native code in Android NDK. The game has 3 main ndk pthreads:

1. a game thread
2. a server communication thread
3. the main rendering thread (called through Renderer.onRender)

Other than that, on java side, we are using AdWhirl which spawns their own thread through their own `ScheduledExecutorService`, but we have wrapped every call to "schedule", "submit", "post", "start" etc with try-catch block to catch the `RejectedExecutionException`. However, the dreadly `RejectedExecutionException` still occurs on every new versions we submitted.

The stack trace from Android Market leaves hardly any more clues for me and our QA department also find it difficult to pinpoint the problem as it hardly occur during test (only our users reported crash). It affects only a small portion of our users but still it is more than 7,000 crashes per week (small portion compared with high number of install base)

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
at         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1876)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1295)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:394)
at c.onProgressUpdate(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1961)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1315)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:394)
at c.onProgressUpdate(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1876)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1295)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:394)
at c.onProgressUpdate(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 17):

While you should of course try to keep things as efficient as possible, there is no arbitrary limit to the number of threads you are "allowed" to run, it all depends on how you structure your code.

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class is *extremely* well documented, and is where the issue you're seeing is originating. I would [recommend reading through it](http://source.android.com/.), check out

To start with I'm guessing that you're building this with Ant and aren't using these parameters on your javac node:

```
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
```

Either that or the obfuscator you are apparently using are the reason that what would normally be the most important part of a stack trace is instead simply outputting:

```
c.onProgressUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

This is the current ICS 4.0.4 source for ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy, as you can see it's basically a catch-all that always throws an exception:

```
 /**
 * A handler for rejected tasks that throws a
 * {@code RejectedExecutionException}.
 */

public static class AbortPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    /**
     * Creates an {@code AbortPolicy}.
     */
    public AbortPolicy() { }

    /**
     * Always throws RejectedExecutionException.
     *
     * @param r the runnable task requested to be executed
     * @param e the executor attempting to execute this task
     * @throws RejectedExecutionException always.
     */
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
        throw new RejectedExecutionException("Task " + r.toString() +
                                             " rejected from " +
                                             e.toString());
    }
}
```

Additionally, you'll find the defaultHandler declared at the top of ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
private static final RejectedExecutionHandler defaultHandler = new AbortPolicy();
```

So finally, if you look at the default Constructor for ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
                          ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
         threadFactory, defaultHandler);
}
```

You'll see that it's instantiating itself using it's `AbortPolicy` class, which is its default `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` also includes several other `RejectedExecutionHandler` subclasses that you could set as the default, such as:

```
  /**
 * A handler for rejected tasks that silently discards the
 * rejected task.
 */
public static class DiscardPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    /**
     * Creates a {@code DiscardPolicy}.
     */
    public DiscardPolicy() { }

    /**
     * Does nothing, which has the effect of discarding task r.
     *
     * @param r the runnable task requested to be executed
     * @param e the executor attempting to execute this task
     */
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
    }
}
```

The other 3 `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructors include a handler option, so you could either create an instance of it using a different handler, or create you're own subclass, similar to this:

```
package com.justinbuser;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class NoThrowThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private static final RejectedExecutionHandler defaultHandler = new AdoptPolicy();

    public NoThrowThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
        setRejectedExecutionHandler(defaultHandler);
    }

    public NoThrowThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
            ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, defaultHandler);
    }

    public NoThrowThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
            RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
    }

    public NoThrowThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
            ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, defaultHandler);
    }

    public static class AdoptPolicy extends ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy {

        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
            new RejectedExecutionException("Task " + r.toString() + " rejected from " + e.toString()).printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the guide!
I am working and building on eclipse, I did not modify any of the javac params so unless by default javac debug is set to true, it wont be included in my build.

yeah, this is a tricky and time consuming problem to solve.. I havent found any solution either and has since move on to Google's AdMob mediation to substitute AdWhirl. This successfully avoid the RejectedExecution problem :P I will take a look at it again when I have time. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin My answer is outdated, you are right (up-voted etc). Also this is not a forum, I've edited out the noise, [please read the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 13):

You'll have to check your code, it is creating far too many AsyncTask's than it is allowed to.

The [policy](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) is set to

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 10;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 10;
```

<sub>Note: this varies in the different versions of Android</sub>

Comment: I see! Thanks for your clue, is there anyway to increase the size or is there any limit?
In our code, we are not using so many AsyncTask, but we use ScheduledExecutorService and other executors and specify larger threadpool. There are quite a lot of those executors, is there any hard limit for the total number of threads on all executors?

If there is a combined application-wide thread count limit, I will have to check that... at one point in time, our apps are running with more than 20 threads...

Comment: There is no hard limit as per Diane, but it is a best practice to keep in in the 10's. You can set the [maximum pool size](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize(int))

Comment: As I have rewritten the app to use lesser Runnable and AsyncTask, and it is now working and did not see any RejectedExecutionException anymore. Thanks Reno and Diane!

Comment: Please be careful and don't confuse thread pool size with queue size.  The threadpoolsize is the max number of threads that can run at one time to service the queue.  The queue size is how long the queue can get.  What's causing the rejected execution exception is the queue size, NOT the pool size.  As of 2.1 the queue size is indeed 10, although the pool size is actually 128: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/AsyncTask.java

Answer (score 0):

> New tasks submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable) will be rejected when the Executor has been shut down, and also when the Executor uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity, and is saturated.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java