# Android rejectedexecutionexception Task rejected from ThreadPool Executor like a million times

Tags: java, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I am refreshing  my ListView after every 2 seconds using the Async Task. To do this , I am using ScheduledExecutorService to do the same task after every 2 seconds. But I am getting this wired problem ..RejectedExecutionException..I also refered to some posts like

[RejectedExecutionException from AsyncTask, but haven't hit limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529309/rejectedexecutionexception-from-asynctask-but-havent-hit-limits),
[Avoiding RejectedExecutionException in Android 4.4 when app uses list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343563/avoiding-rejectedexecutionexception-in-android-4-4-when-app-uses-list)

did't get the solution. Please help ..
Thnx in advance :)

Error stack:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.stripe.android.compat.AsyncTask$3@23e7c86b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@16831fc8[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
    at com.stripe.android.compat.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:536)
    at com.stripe.android.compat.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:481)
    at com.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.BookACabFragment$3$1.run(BookACabFragment.java:492)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I am starting my scheduler in onResume like this:

```
public void startTimeScheduledExecutorService(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "start scheduler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.startGetCabs="startGetCabs";
                        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
                        scheduledFuture =   scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            AsyncTask.class.getMethod("setDefaultExecutor", Executor.class).invoke(null, AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
                                            GetOnlineDriversNoBar g = new GetOnlineDriversNoBar();
                                            g.execute();
                                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });




//

            }
        },0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
```

And i am stopping my scheduler in onPause and onStop like this:

```
   public void stopTimeScheduledExecutorService() {
        if(startGetCabs.equalsIgnoreCase("startGetCabs")){
        if (!scheduledFuture.isCancelled()) {
            scheduledFuture.cancel(true);


           // scheduler.shutdown();
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "shutdown scheduler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //  timer = null;
        }}
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen ***after*** you called ``stopTimeScheduledExecutorService()``?

Comment: yes... And I using these methods startTimeScheduledExecutorService() and stopTimeScheduledExecutorService() like 2 times

Comment: 2 times..meaning ... starting  and then restarting  on Start and stop buttons

Comment: the stopTimeScheduledExecutorService does not stop the scheduler at all? is it a typo?

Comment: @fdreger .. sry didnt get u ?? its the code for stopping the Scheduler..  i am using this when Activity is no longer visible to  user

Comment: @JeanLogeart...fdreger .. please help if you can .. thnx in advance