# How can I get a RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, pool

Anybody able to provide me with an example of getting a [RejectedExecutionException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html)
Possibly a real life example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: shutdown the executor and then submit a new task.

Comment: `throw new RejectedExecutionException();`

Comment: LOL!!! Classic @Renan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Anybody able to provide me with an example of getting a RejectedExecutionException Possibly a real life example.

Sure.  The following code submits 2 jobs into a thread-pool with only 1 thread running.  It uses a `SynchronousQueue` which means that no jobs will be stored in the job queue.

Since each job takes a while to run, the 2nd execute fills the queue and throws a `RejectedExecutionException`.

```
// create a 1 thread pool with no buffer for the runnable jobs
ExecutorService threadPool =
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
// submit 2 jobs that take a while to run
/// this job takes the only thread
threadPool.execute(new SleepRunnable());
// this tries to put the job into the queue, throws RejectedExecutionException
threadPool.execute(new SleepRunnable());

public class SleepRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // this just sleeps for a while which pauses the thread
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This is happening by design because the queue is full and all of the threads are busy.  If you want to avoid this problem then you should create a larger queue to store more jobs when all of the worker threads are busy, increase the number of threads working on the jobs (although you can only increase this so far), or block the code that is submitting the jobs to the thread-pool.  See: [How to implement blocking thread pool executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650732/how-to-implement-blocking-thread-pool-executor/44658960#44658960)

Comment: Can you describe in words what this causes and why, for reference for future users?

Comment: How would you avoid this error? Is it by implementing rate limiter ?

Comment: @JayModi See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650732/how-to-implement-blocking-thread-pool-executor/44658960#44658960

Answer (score 4):

Sending tasks to an executor after calling `shutdown(` on it will throw this exception.

In addition, if the executor uses a bounded blocking queue if the queue is full submitting the task will not block but will fail-fast with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked and answered :
[What could be the cause of RejectedExecutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183205/what-could-cause-of-rejectedexecutionexception)
[Submitting tasks to a thread-pool gives RejectedExecutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788672/android-rejectedexecutionexception)

This code gives you the error because we try to launch the task but the executor is shut down you can refer to the link above for further explications the answer looked pretty complete:

```
public class Executorz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executorz ex = new Executorz();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i<100 ; i++){
            System.out.println("Executed");
            es.execute(ex.getNewCountin());

            if (i==20)
                es.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public Countin getNewCountin(){
        return new Countin();
    }

    public class Countin implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (double i =0; i<1000000000 ; i++){
            }           
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
}
```